# XML Node data for SUDZc

Tags: wsdl, xcode4.3

Hi I'm getting this result for WSDL response while i'm using sudzc website instruction, Any one help me how can i access these values.
Thanks in Advance :)

```
AuthenticateRequest returned the value: {
    AuthenticateRequestResult =     {
       diffgram = {
            NewDataSet = {
                Table = {
                    CDS = 48705400000000;
                    IsActive = false;
                    Parameters = "<null>";
                    "User_ID" = scdistrict;
                };
            };
        };
    schema = {
        element = {
            complexType =  {
                choice = {
                    element = {
                        complexType = {
                            sequence =  {
                                element = 0;
                            };
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this xml to NSDictionary, (see [this](https://github.com/bcaccinolo/XML-to-NSDictionary)), then fetch the desired attributes you want from the dictionary.